# Limits and ranges of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

There is no function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and with range equals to $[-2,5) \cup (-7,-4]$.

True or false? If true, prove. If false, give counterexample.

I think it is true.

Let $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous on $\mathbb R$. Suppose the range of $f$ is $[-2,5) \cup (-7,-4]$. This means that:

$\lim_{x \to {{x_0}^-}} f(x) = -4$
$\lim_{x \to {{x_0}^+}} f(x) = -2$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb R$.

Since  $\lim_{x \to {{x_0}^-}} f(x)$ is not equal to $\lim_{x \to {{x_0}^+}} f(x)$, $f$ cannot be continuous. We reach a contradiction. Therefore there is no such functions.

Am I right?

Comment: You are on the wrong track. Start over, and review the statement of the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Ok. Now that we know the intervals don't overlap, Rafflesia's advice is good.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true, but I am unsure of your proof. You should use the Intermediate Value Theorem. Since, for example, $-5$ and $3$ are in the range of $f$, then there are $x,y$ such that $f(x) = -5$ and $f(y) = 3$. Assume that $x<y$. Then, by the IVT, for every number $c$ with $-5 < c < 3$, there exists some $z, x<z<y$ such that $f(z) = c$. However, if we let $c = -3$, then $-5 < -3 < 3$, but there is no $z$ such that $f(z) = -3$ because $-3$ is not in the range of $f$. The case that $y<x$ is similar.

Comment: Yes, I realized my answer is wrong. So for a complete proof, I should do the same way you did for $x>y$ and for $y>x$?

Comment: Yes. Consider reading up on the Intermediate Value Theorem at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem.

Comment: Ok, so basically you proved using the contradiction method right?

Comment: Yes, I should have explicitly mentioned that. What I did was assume that there does exist a continuous function with the specified range, and then I showed that this contradicted the IVT.

Comment: For the case where $y<x$, can we take they same numbers but this time we take: $f(y) = -5$ and $f(x)=3$?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much!